# Function inside object in symfony form builder

Tags: php, forms, function, symfony

I don`t know why i am getting error if i try this:

```
$builder
->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
'data' => $options['product'],
'placeholder' => 'Wyszukiwarka',
'mapped' => false,
'multiple' => false,
'class' => Products::class,
'attr' => [
    'class' => 'chosen-select order_product',
    'data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz produkt',
    'single_price' => function ($product) {
       $cena = $product->getJson()["products"]["price"];
      dump($cena);
      return $cena;
      }
  ],

'choice_label' => function ($product) {
return  ''.$product->getJson()["products"]["name"] .' | Stan Magazynowy: '.$product->getJson()["products"]["stock"].'';
},
'label' => 'Wybierz produkty'

))
```

so, function inside 'choice_label' works perfect, why i can`t do the same in attr which contains a par extra attributes for this input. 
I am getting this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string").
```

Why function inside attr object not working ?

Comment: Symfony's form builder lets you provide a callback for any of the top level options (data, placeholder, etc), but I don't think you can use a callback for an individual form attribute. You should be able to refactor this to provide a callback that generates the entire `attr` array, rather than just for the `single_price` element.

Comment: `'attr' => function ($product) {
          $cena = $product->getJson()["products"]["price"];
          return array(
            'class' => 'chosen-select order_product',
            'data-placeholder' => 'Wybierz produkt',
            'single_price' => $cena,
          );
          },`

Comment: I still gettin: `The option "attr" with value Closure is expected to be of type "array", but is of type "Closure".`

Comment: You need to use `choice_attr` instead of `attr`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong configuration option. The `attr` option doesn't accept a callback. In your case - to add an attribute depending on the value of each choice - you need to use `choice_attr` as found in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr).

An example implementation could look like this:

```
$builder->add('attending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    // [..]
    'choice_attr' => function($choiceValue, $key, $product) {
        return [
            'data-single-price' => $product->getPrice()
        ];
    }
));
```

Comment: yes exaclly, becouse attr is for select, and choices_attr is for every single option. Thx !

Comment: Does someone know how to test the call back in phpunit?